# Is it possible to use a Coup D’etat covert operation on a civilization's last city?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I had managed to hem in a rival civ by aggressively expanding out towards them, and then spent a bunch of time annexing their cities through the Coup D’etat covert operation. I managed to pick off 2 out of their 3 cities, including their capital. However, I spent two operations to Coup their last remaining city with failure both times. I then got impatient and simply took it by force over the next couple turns.

Is it possible to run a successful Coup D’etat operation on the last remaining city of a civilization?

Answer (score 1):

**It certainly is possible, and very do-able.**

The wiki page state that **Each city has an “intrigue level” which reflects how much clandestine activity is going on there,** and if a city has an intrigue level it can be captured. There are no restrictions on it being the "last city".

The reason your Coup D`etat failed is because of a question that I answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190089/how-does-one-effectively-increase-intrigue/190095#190095). I state that no matter what you have, there is always a chance for the Covert Ops mission to fail. Thus, why the operation was unsuccessful for the first time. Now, when you failed that operation there is several possibilities to what could have happened after as a result:

- **You just got unlucky.** This is always a possibility on any covert ops mission.
- **An Agent(s) with a high Agent Rank died after the first unsuccessful Coup D`etat mission**, resulting in a decreased chance of you completing the Covert Ops mission. **

It is good to mention that not always after an unsuccessful covert ops mission will your Agents die. There are four possible outcomes:

> **Undetected:** The defending player is not notified that anything has happened.
>
> **Detected:** The defending player is notified that a covert operation took place, but  not who perpetrated it.
>
> **Identified:** The defending player is notified that a covert operation took place and who perpetrated it. The agent is returned to Headquarters (escapes).
>
> **Killed:** The defending player is notified that a covert operation took place and who perpetrated it. The agent is killed.

[Source](http://civilizationbeyondearth.gamepedia.com/Covert_Ops)

Comment: So none of this information is particularly new to me, and I realize that I could have just been unlucky. But I'm hoping to be able to point to something that says that you can completely absorb a rival civilization without any military engagements through covert-ops.

Comment: @Ellesedil Then you asked the wrong question. I answered "Is it possible to run a successful Coup D’etat operation on the last remaining city of a civilization?" which is Yes. Your next question "I'm hoping to be able to point to something that says that you can completely absorb a rival civilization without any military engagements through covert-ops." is totally different then what you were asking in your original question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is that any different? It's obvious you can take cities with Coups. I just want to confirm that you can take every city, and specifically, the very last city a civilization controls.

Comment: Yes you can. @Ellesedil That's why I mentioned : It certainly is possible, and very do-able.

The wiki page state that Each city has an “intrigue level” which reflects how much clandestine activity is going on there, and if a city has an intrigue level it can be captured. There are no restrictions on it being the "last city".

Comment: Yes, I understand the documentation and I understand that it does not explicitly state any restrictions. There's also plenty of other pieces of information that is not documented. Do you have an example or first-hand experience that you can relate to using a successful Coup operation on a civ's last city?

Comment: @Ellesedil Why not just replay it multiple times (before you took it by force) and see if you can? Doesn't seem like it should be hard to test.

Comment: @AHungerArtist: It would be easy to test. However, I no longer have a game state that makes it easy to test as I've progressed quite a bit since then and I overwrite my save file. I'd need to spin up a brand new game and progress through it quite a bit to definitively test it. There is a 4-city civ on a seperate continent in my game that I could start up with, but I'm not sure I'll be able to run enough ops before the game ends.